# Kubernetes Ingress controller - Traefik vs Tectonic vs Nginx

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I am exploring ingress and came across the following ingress controllers:

- Traefik
- Tectonic
- Nginx

I have googled a lot, but seems no such big difference. Could you please help me with differences between these 3 and the best choice to use in production?

**Note:** This is for my private cloud using Linux VM's.

Thanks.

Comment: Tectonic is a commercial packaging of kubernetes. You should not use that unless you are running Tectonic.

Comment: The big difference between nginx and traefik is popularity, maturity and configuration model. nginx is much more popular, much more mature, has a complex configuration model, and requires explicit changes when something in the cluster changes. Traefik is less mature, less well known, and can infer configuration changes directly from cluster metadata. If you're familiar with neither, use nginx.

Comment: I dont agree with you, for simple use case traefik is more than enough. It allow configuration on the flow that work well with kubernetes (= no service interruption when reloading configuration) and provide auto ssl renewal.
Btw, on the other side, nginx configuration has many features and can be easily extended.

Comment: Nice article on this subject: https://medium.com/@andreidascalu/nginx-vs-traefik-vs-haproxy-cc99546f676a